# PhoneGap slider support not functioning properly

Tags: jquery-mobile, cordova

Working with PhoneGap  attempting to add a label and slider to an iOS  iPad application, both the label and the slider will not appear on the page.  The following is the code intended to generate the display:

```html
<div data-role="fieldcontain">
    <label for="quantity">Number of Cones:</label>
    <input type="range" name="quantity" id="quantity" value="5" min="1" max="10" />
</div>
```

The above snippet properly produces:

```
Number of Cones:
<------|------->
```

but fails to display the label box with quantity initialized to 5.

What is the cause of this issue?

Comment: You gotta give us more info. That exact code works fine when I try it.